# Powershell generating unknown character when echoing to file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to echo 3 plain-text lines to a file using Powershell:

```
echo "#Generated" > psftp.scp
echo "put test.txt" >> psftp.scp
echo "quit" >> psftp.scp
```

I then use psftp.exe batch mode to run the file (executes the commands in SFTP), but psftp errors out seeing an invalid character:

```
psftp: unknown command " ■#"
```

What am I missing? I can manually type up the file in Windows Notepad and it (psftp) works. No matter what I change the first line to (`#Generated`) it gets this error with the block symbol in the first part.

I've tried viewing the file in NotePad++ w/ "Show All Symbols" on, but only saw CR & LF at the end of lines which is normal.

Comment: Someone else can verify this, but it may be a bom character or something that windows includes after the strings. If you use `Out-File` you can use `-Append` to add text and `-Encoding` to specify the correct encoding.

Comment: fwiw, the characters are 0xFF, 0xFE, then the letters, but with 0x00 between them.(I don't _think_ that's unicode)

Comment: And the comment by @FrodeF. works.  Without the -encoding ascii, it still has the weird characters at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Does anyone know *why* Powershell's redirect behaves so obnoxiously? It seems like something that should be easily fixed to behave more similarly to bash and not insert random characters. I am assuming there is some reason.

Comment: @mbourgon, it is _a_ Unicode encoding, namely UTF-16LE (mistakenly called "Unicode" in PowerShell).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using set/add-content instead of redirection.  You might also need to set the encoding.

```
"#Generated" | set-content psftp.scp -Encoding Ascii
"put test.txt" | add-content psftp.scp -Encoding Ascii
"quit" | add-content psftp.scp -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: I ended up doing "Default" encoding and it was fine.

Comment: Do you know *why* powershell behaves like this? Why does it insert seemingly random characters when redirecting a cmdline string to a file?

Comment: I can confirm that for me it didn't work to set the encoding as utf8, but "Default" worked

Comment: NotePad++ = UTF-8 --
PowerShell UTF8 = UTF-8-BOM -- PowerShell Default = UTF-8 --
Settings confirmed in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Like Out-File, the default encoding of ">" and ">>" in Powershell 5 is UTF16LE ("Unicode").  I guess psftp can't read that?  "FF FE" is the encoding signature or "BOM".  How are you running psftp?

```
format-hex psftp.scp


           Path: C:\Users\me\psftp.scp

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF FE 23 00 47 00 65 00 6E 00 65 00 72 00 61 00  .þ#.G.e.n.e.r.a.
00000010   74 00 65 00 64 00 0D 00 0A 00 70 00 75 00 74 00  t.e.d.....p.u.t.
00000020   20 00 74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 2E 00 74 00 78 00   .t.e.s.t...t.x.
00000030   74 00 0D 00 0A 00 71 00 75 00 69 00 74 00 0D 00  t.....q.u.i.t...
00000040   0A 00                                            ..
```

Set the default encoding for ">", ">>" and out-file in powershell 5.1:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'Ascii'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was piping a .ps1 into powershell in a .cmd file

```
type script.ps1 | powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Although the script had no errors when run in other ways, when run this way, it would throw a syntax error on the first row (a comment row) due to invalid characters.

I found out that if I saved the .ps1 file with the wScite editor, the default was "UTF-8 with BOM".  I changed it to just "UTF-8", and after that piping the script to powershell worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, an attempt at a systematic overview:

- In the modern, cross-platform **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** edition (v6 and above), it is now fine to use `>` and `>>` as they now create ***BOM-less [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)*** files (as *all* file-writing cmdlets now do *consistently*).

  - Given that many modern programs expect this character encoding, **your code will likely work as-is**.
  - If you need a different encoding, call a cmdlet with `-Encoding`, as discussed next.
- In the legacy ***Windows PowerShell*** edition (whose latest and final version is v5.1), **`>` and `>>` default to [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)** (which PowerShell incorrectly calls `Unicode`), which few external programs understand, and which is the cause of your problem.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - `>` and `>>` are in effect alias of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and `Out-File -Append`, and specifying a *different* encoding requires calling them explicitly with an `-Encoding` argument.
  - However, with *string* input, you may use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) and [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content), which **default** to `Default`, representing the **system's active ANSI code page**, such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on US-English systems.

    ```bash
    # `-Encoding Default` implied.
    # OK with ASCII-only characters, otherwise only if the program
    # expects ANSI encoding.
    # If you use -Encoding ASCII, any non-ASCII characters become
    # *literal ?* chars., i.e. information is *lost*.
    # (That can also happen for `-Encoding Default` for Unicode chars.
    # outside the character set of the active ANSI code page.)
    '#Generated' | Set-Content psftp.scp
    'put test.txt' | Add-Content psftp.scp
    'quit' | Add-Content psftp.scp
    ```
  - It gets tricky **if you want *BOM-less UTF-8***, because Windows PowerShell's cmdlets do *not* support creating such files - `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates files *with* a BOM (unlike in *PowerShell (Core)*, where you conversely must use `-Encoding utf8bom` to explicitly request a BOM).  Curiously, [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) *does* create BOM-less UTF-8 files, so it can be used to create the file, which allows subsequent `Add-Content` calls to use `-Encoding utf8` safely, because they won't add a BOM to *existing* file content.

    ```bash
    # New-Item, curiously, creates BOM-less UTF-8 files.
    # The string must be passed via -Value (or as a *single* pipeline input), 
    # and a trailing newline must be added explicitly.
    $null = New-Item -Force psftp.scp -Value "#Génerated`n"
    'put test.txt' | Add-Content -Encoding utf8 psftp.scp
    'quit' | Add-Content -Encoding utf8 psftp.scp
    ```

---

<sup>[1] UTF-16LE files created by PowerShell *always* have a [BOM (Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is the 2-byte sequence `0xFF`, `0xFE`, and characters / surrogate-pair halves are represented as *16-bit code units*, i.e. as *two* bytes, with ASCII-range characters having `0x0` (`NUL`) as the second byte in their two-byte sequence.</sup>